# ColdFusion "Content not allowed in prolog" XML with NO Bom

Tags: xml, coldfusion

I'm having some trouble parsing an XML file with ColdFusion.
I've double, triple-checked the file for the BOM, which *doesn't* exist.

The twist, the code only happens when I use `<cfinvoke>`.
So, on **index.cfm**

```
<cfinvoke component='controller.me' method='ADQuery'>
</cfinvoke>
```

**Controller/Me.cfc**

```
<cffunction name='ADQuery' output='true'>
<cfset netinfoxml = XMLParse(ExpandPath('conf/netinfo.xml'))>
```

Then it all goes wrong. 
However, if I do it directly from index.cfm, and dump it. Then it's fine.

Any ideas?

Sorry, it's probably something incredibly trivial

Comment: (Edit) Does `ExpandPath('conf/netinfo.xml')` evaluate to the same path inside index.cfm and Controller/Me.cfc?

Comment: ie If the file path is invalid, XMLParse might end up thinking the xml is literally the string "c:/path/to/FileThatDoesNotExist.xml". Hence the *Content is not allowed in prolog* error.

Comment: @Leigh Yeah afaik. In index.cfm the line is `ExpandPath('controller/conf/network.xml')` and jn me.cfc it's `ExpandPath('conf/network.xml')`. I see your point. (EDIT) I've also dropped the xml in the same folder as `Me.cfc`. nope x-(. I'm hoping I haven't been a doughnut here...

Comment: Glad Sean helped you find the problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this will help, seems to be a pretty in depth description [and solution!] to your problem....

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1206-Content-Is-Not-Allowed-In-Prolog-ColdFusion-XML-And-The-Byte-Order-Mark-BOM-.htm

If not, can you post the xml?

-sean

Comment: Hi Sean. Thanks for the heads up. The number of times I've read that article is insane, but I never thought of actually `cfhttp`ing the xml file. More like, I kinda forgot how to (woops...) link to the xml file, even though it's static. Back to my original function. I removed the ExpandPath part and it now works fine (apart from LDAP auth, but that's because I've not written that yet). Thanks for your help!

So. I did that. It worked, parsing. It worked.